# Formula Field: Combine number formula and text formula

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have two formula fields.

**First formula is a *number* formula:**

```
(First_Response_Date_Time__c - CreatedDate )*24
```

it calculates Time to First Response (in hrs)

**Second formula is a *text* formula:**

```
IF(AND( Time_to_First_Response__c <8, TEXT(Type) = "Wonoloer"), " ✅",
IF(AND( Time_to_First_Response__c >= 8 , Time_to_First_Response__c <= 12, TEXT(Type) = "Wonoloer"), " ⚠️",
IF(AND( Time_to_First_Response__c > 12, TEXT(Type) = "Wonoloer") , "",
IF(AND( Time_to_First_Response__c < 2, TEXT(Type) = "Requestor"), " ✅",
IF(AND( Time_to_First_Response__c >= 2, Time_to_First_Response__c <= 4, TEXT(Type) = "Requestor"), "⚠️",
IF(AND( Time_to_First_Response__c > 4, TEXT(Type) = "Requestor") , " ", ""
))))))
```

**How can I insert the second formula into the first formula so that the output may look like this:** 4 ✅

I'd like to be able to see how many hours to first response in hours plus the designated icon, in short, **I need to show the number of hours and the emoji icon next to it.**

Preferably, I'd like to show this in the first formula instead of having 2 separate forumlas.

Any help or direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need text, the first formula would have to be changed to text. Aside from that, you can use the `&` (text concatenation operator) to combine both:

```
TEXT((First_Response_Date_Time__c - CreatedDate )*24) &
IF(AND( Time_to_First_Response__c <8, TEXT(Type) = "Wonoloer"), " ✅",
IF(AND( Time_to_First_Response__c >= 8 , Time_to_First_Response__c <= 12, TEXT(Type) = "Wonoloer"), " ⚠️",
IF(AND( Time_to_First_Response__c > 12, TEXT(Type) = "Wonoloer") , "",
IF(AND( Time_to_First_Response__c < 2, TEXT(Type) = "Requestor"), " ✅",
IF(AND( Time_to_First_Response__c >= 2, Time_to_First_Response__c <= 4, TEXT(Type) = "Requestor"), "⚠️",
IF(AND( Time_to_First_Response__c > 4, TEXT(Type) = "Requestor") , " ", ""
))))))
```